# Recursively remove property from Zod object

Tags: typescript, zod

With a complex Zod object, I would like to recursively search for a property `someProp` and remove it wherever it exists, possibly using `.omit({ someProp: true })`.  Here is an attempt that does not work...

```
function removeSomeProp<T extends ZodRawShape>(obj: T): T {
  const result: any = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    const value = obj[key];

    if (value instanceof ZodObject) {
      result[key] = removeSomeProp(value.shape);
    } else {
      result[key] = value;
    }
  });

  return z.object(result).omit({ someProp: true }) as unknown as T;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with...  Note that once it find a `someProp` property, it no longer recurses down that branch.  This also  makes a few assumptions about the shape of the ZodObject.

```
function removeSomeProp(schema: ZodTypeAny): ZodTypeAny {
  if (schema instanceof ZodObject) {
    if (schema.shape["someProp" as keyof typeof schema.shape]) {
      return schema.omit({ someProp: true });
    }

    const newObj: any = {};
    Object.keys(schema.shape).forEach((key) => {
      newObj[key as keyof typeof newObj] = removeSomeProp(schema.shape[key as keyof typeof schema.shape]);
    });
    return z.object(newObj);
  }
  if (schema instanceof ZodOptional) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
    return removeSomeProp(schema._def.innerType);
  }
  if (schema instanceof ZodArray) {
    return removeSomeProp(schema.element);
  }

  return schema;
}
```